# Multitouch issue with two buttons: always get the same buttons even when I press two different ones, why?

Tags: android, button, multi-touch

i have two buttons, which make a sound if they are pressed. I'd like to press both at the same time to hear the two sounds at the same time. So far:

@Override
      // Handle touches of the navigation arrows
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

```
    int action = event.getActionMasked();

    switch (action){

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         switch (v.getId()) { // Which button?
            case R.id.cnotebutton: // The upArrow
                Log.i("C", "C");
              //  mSoundPool.stop(mStream1);
                //mStream1= mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(1), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1,0, 1f);
                break;
            case R.id.dnotebutton: // The downArrow
                  Log.i("D", "D");
                 // mSoundPool.stop(mStream2);
                //mStream2= mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(2), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1,0, 1f);
                break;
            default:
            }

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;  
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
             switch (v.getId()) { // Which button?
                case R.id.cnotebutton: // The upArrow
                    Log.i("C", "C");
                  //  mSoundPool.stop(mStream1);
                    //mStream1= mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(1), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1,0, 1f);
                    break;
                case R.id.dnotebutton: // The downArrow
                      Log.i("D", "D");
                     // mSoundPool.stop(mStream2);
                    //mStream2= mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(2), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1,0, 1f);
                    break;
                default:
                }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            break;
        default:

    }
    return true;
}
```

It does not work. How should I solve this? Another question if I move my finger on the screen I would like to press the button when my finger reached a button without raising up it. ACTION_MOVE doenst work either. Sorry for the dumb question i am pretty beginner at this area.

**UPDATE**

With this code it detects the multitouch, but I got always two same logs, as if I touched always the same button with both of my fingers. So even if i press the two buttons at the same time I get a log "C" and another "C" which is wrong, i should get C and D.

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you playing with a SurfaceView? I have the feeling that not. Why don't you simply set the OnClickListener of each Button?

Otherwise, you need to access each touch event separately: see paragraph "index vs. ID" at http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html: maybe it will help you

Serge

Comment: No I dont use surfaceview, should i? Why would it be better? If I simply set the onClickListener for each button it still wont work.

Comment: I checked the source code of the game I made and indeed I've worked with onTouchListener. Maybe you should return True instead of false if you handled the event?

Comment: nothing changed :S it still plays the sound that it detected first.

Answer (score 0):

Does your code look like this? I highlighted some key points

package be.domore.smokesignaltest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DummyActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    private Button myButton1;
    private Button myButton2;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the content view
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dummy);

    // Map controls
    mapControls();
}

private void mapControls() {
    myButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton1);
    myButton1.setOnTouchListener(this);

    myButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton2);
    myButton2.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    **if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)**
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.myButton1:
            // TODO: put your code here
            **return true;**
        case R.id.myButton2:
            // TODO: put your code here
            **return true;**
        }

    *return false;*
}
```

}

The following class is a helper I created to manage sounds. The interesting part is the function AssignSoundToView. I don't know if it will help you?

package be.domore.FingerTwister.Game;

import java.io.IOException;

import be.domore.FingerTwister.Settings;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class SoundManager2 {
    private static SoundManager2 current = new SoundManager2();

```
public static SoundManager2 getCurrent() {
    return current;
}

private boolean initialized = false;
private MediaPlayer player;
private SoundPool pool;
private AssetManager assetManager;

private int[] soundId = new int[Sounds.values().length];
private int[] soundStream = new int[Sounds.values().length];

private SoundManager2() {

}

public void assignSoundToView(View view, Sounds sound) {
    final int currentSound;

    if (Settings.hasFx() == false) {

    } else if (sound != Sounds.none) {
        currentSound = sound.ordinal();

        view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                try {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        pool.play(soundId[currentSound], 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0,
                                1);
                } finally {
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}

public boolean initialize(Activity activity) {

    if (initialized == false) {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        pool = new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        assetManager = activity.getAssets();
        activity.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        for (int idx = 1; idx < Sounds.values().length; idx++)
            soundId[idx] = loadSound(
                    String.format("%s.mp3", Sounds.values()[idx]),
                    assetManager);

        initialized = true;
    } else
        Log.w("SoundManager", "SoundManager was already initialized");

    return initialized;
}

public boolean isInitialized() {
    return initialized;
}

private int loadSound(String filename, AssetManager assetManager) {
    int rc;
    AssetFileDescriptor afd;

    try {
        afd = assetManager.openFd(filename);
        rc = pool.load(afd, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        rc = 0;
    }

    return rc;
}

public boolean playMusic(String filename) {
    boolean rc = false;
    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;

    if (initialized == false)
        Log.e("SoundManager", "SoundManager is not initialized");
    else
        try {
            descriptor = assetManager.openFd(filename);
            player.reset();
            player.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                    descriptor.getStartOffset(),
                    descriptor.getDeclaredLength());
            player.setLooping(true);
            // player.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();

            rc = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return rc;
}

public void playSound(Sounds sound) {
    int index;

    index = sound.ordinal();
    soundStream[index] = pool.play(soundId[index], 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1);
}

public void stopAllSound() {
    for (int idx = 1; idx < Sounds.values().length; idx++)
        stopSound(Sounds.values()[idx]);
}

public boolean stopMusic() {
    boolean rc = false;

    if (initialized == false)
        Log.e("SoundManager", "SoundManager is not initialized");
    else {
        player.stop();
        rc = true;
    }

    return rc;
}

public void stopSound(Sounds sound) {
    int index;

    index = sound.ordinal();
    pool.stop(soundStream[index]);
}
```

}

Comment: I Can assure you there is multitouch: that's how I build my game Finger Twister (up to 10 contact points)

Comment: updated my code in your style. Tried to log the multitouch but nothing happens, only the first button gives me a log.

Comment: Sorry to only suggest stupid ideas: maybe you could add a default case in your switch only to be sure your other buttons trigger one case? You could also put a breakpoint on the switch and run your application in debug mode so that you will directly see how is your code running

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code, but until I dont get logs from both buttons, sounds wont work either. Maybe ACTION_POINTER is that I should use, isn't it?

Comment: updated my code, do you have any idea why it detects the same buttons always?